# RPI2 connect througth SPI with CC3100

Tags: raspberry-pi2, spi

Have somebody experience with it? and run SPI_Debug_Tool program successfull? 
I installed driver cc3100-linux own my RPI2. I connected through SPI with WIFI module cc3100. I tested program SPI_Debug_Tool, but it same point stop run. It'll not run all. (picture)

[image]